# For Android google maps API V2 how do you set zindex of marker?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I'm basically trying to figure out how in a cluster of markers to make a marker become selected without clicking on it?  Or bring it to the top?  I can't seem to find any API methods for this.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey could you find any solution to this problem , Please share i can't find any

Comment: The conclusion I came to at the time is that it wasn't possible.

Comment: @user1530779 this SO may solve the problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/38060679/4284706

Comment: it's possible, use marker.setZIndex(float value)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There aren't any. Unfortunately, `Marker`s in Google Map API V2 for Android do not have z-indices. They handle their own draw order.